# MySQL - cannot examine view definition - Error getting DDL for object - No database selected

Tags: mysql, view, errors

I have a view that I can run, it returns a dataset, but whenever I try to alter the view or look at its definition, I get

```
Error getting DDL for object
No database selected
```

[image]

But I do have a database selected and I can run the view with results.

How do I recover the definition?  Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`No database selected` error message means that no database is selected as current. Specify default database in my.ini, connection definition, or execute `USE dbname;` as the very first query in the connection.

> why no other view required a default schema be defined, and why is a default schema required at all? – Roy Hinkley

Default scheme needed when tablename without database name is specified somewhere in SQL text.

For example, you execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_view` - but without default datatbase set the server does not know where it must take this view from (and even does this is a table or a view).